# Javascript Canvas blank Tizen webapp

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I try to display video on canvas in a Samsung SmartTV (2017) with (TV extension 3.0) with Html5 & Javascript.

Here is a my sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        font: white
    }
</style>

<body>

    <!-- <video width="820" height="240" controls>
          <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.ogv">
          
        </video> -->
    <video id="source" src="https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4" autoplay muted
        controls></video>
    <hr>
    <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c2"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c3"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c4"></canvas>
    

</body>
<script>
    var video = $('#source')[0]; //variable to tie to our source

    //create an array to store our canvases
    // var splitCanvas = [$('#c1')[0], $('#c2')[0], $('#c3')[0], $('#c4')[0]];
    var splitCanvas = [$('#c1')[0], $('#c2')[0]];


    //start the function once the video starts playing
    video.addEventListener('playing', function () {

        //create some variables for readability
        //halving the width and height results in 4 quadrants
        var w = video.videoWidth / 2;
        var h = video.videoHeight;

        //create a canvas context so we can manipulate the images
        var context = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < splitCanvas
            .length; x++) { //set the canvas dimensions to the native size of the video
            splitCanvas[x].width = w;
            splitCanvas[x].height = h;
            context.push(splitCanvas[x].getContext('2d')); //create the context

        };
        console.log('drawing'); //Draw the 4 quadrants from the source video every 33 ms (approx 30 FPS)
        setInterval(function () { //context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height); //Upper left
            context[0].drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w,
                h
            );
            context[1].drawImage(video,
                w, 0, //x, y start clipping
                w, h, //x, y clipping width
                0, 0, //x, y placement
                w, h); //width, height of placement
        }, 33);
    });
</script>

</html>
```

On emulator and Chrome, it's working without error in chrome devtool:

[image: Emulator demo]

On my TV, video playing but canvas is blank without error on Chrome Devtool:

[image: Device demo]

It's a strange for me because all tests are same, video showing but canvas was empty every time.

I suspect DrawImage,How can i find out where the problem comes from if i don't have any errors in the console and when I add a breakpoint in the drawImage, it continues normally.

[image: DrawImage debug]

any idea or equivalent for display video on canvas?

Comment: Try various video formats + codecs. There used to be such a bug in Android back in the days with mp4, it may be the same kind of issue.

Comment: Try to download asset and put it inside app folder. 
There could be cross-origin issues caused by file:// protocol.

Comment: @Kaiido, multiple format+codecs tested and result is same for all. i'll try with local video for checking if work or not thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it is not supported feature in TV device including newer TV devices.

It is a constraint due to the VIDEO_HOLE method that punches transparency hole at the video area and video is played on overlay(underlay) plane

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Really, it's a bad news for me. I ban Tizen from my life because it's a waste of time for dev, if i can't manipulate image or video on a TV what's the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer as to why it is not working, but I can add some troubleshooting tips (I couldn't fit them as a comment)

1. Try with checking canvas support (I am pretty sure it is supported, but no harm to verify it!)

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200" fill="red">
  Canvas is not supported.
</canvas>
```

2. Start with drawing simple image to check if `drawImage` is working as expected!

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const image = document.getElementById('source');

image.addEventListener('load', e => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg" width="300" height="227">
</div>
```

If `drawImage` is working, most likely reason for issue will be `video` is not supported as a valid argument for `drawImage`.

3. Check version of Tizen on your TV, may be it's time for firmware upgrade! On the [docs](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/w3c/graphics/canvas/#related-information) it is mentioned Tizen 3.0 or higher is required. Easiet way would be to check user agent on your browser:

```js
document.write(navigator.userAgent);
```

Hopefully one of the suggestions will help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i've try and here's the result: 

1) text not showing so it's supported. 

2) Image is showing correctly but not in canvas.

3) the result is : Mozilla/5.0 (SMART-TV; LINUX; Tizen 3.0) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 TV Safari/538.1

Comment: `2) Image is showing correctly but not in canvas` what do you mean by it @Kate?

Comment: image is showing on img tag if i change display none to display block and canvas remains empty without error. i tried an example on mozilla for display image on canvas and it's work well! [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_getimagedata2) but i don't understand why this example is work and my code not?

Comment: @Kate I am sorry I didn't get you. The example on the link is working, the example code I shared is working with dsiplay `none`? Main purpose of `display: none`  is to hide image from `img` tag but display it on `canvas`.

Comment: Also try your code with `setInterval` set to 1000, may be refreshing is an issue.

Comment: sorry, your example with image isn't working because canvas was empty. But when i try with this example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_getimagedata2 it's work.setInterval = 1000 don't change anything :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223485/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-kate).